# How do CancelledError's should be handled in typical aiohttp web servers?

Tags: connection-pooling, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have aiohttp web server application with handlers like:

```
async def handler(request):
    async with request.app["db"].acquire() as db:
        row = await query(db)

    return aiohttp.web.json_response(row)
```

Where `app["db"]` is some kind of pooled resource (`aiopg`, `aioredis`, does not matter now). This worked great until today. For no reason all clients started disconnecting by timeout and application logs filled up with traces like

```
[2017-05-21 17:58:24,254] ERROR    [aiohttp.server] Error handling request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/web_server.py", line 61, in handle_request
    resp = yield from self._handler(request)
  File "/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/web.py", line 249, in _handle
    resp = yield from handler(request)
  File "/visio-longer/visio_longer/views/communicate/__init__.py", line 81, in legacy_communicate
    async with request.app["db"].acquire() as db:
  File "/virtualenv/src/aiopg/aiopg/utils.py", line 140, in __aenter__
    self._conn = yield from self._coro
  File "/virtualenv/src/aiopg/aiopg/sa/engine.py", line 162, in _acquire
    raw = yield from self._pool.acquire()
  File "/virtualenv/src/aiopg/aiopg/utils.py", line 67, in __iter__
    resp = yield from self._coro
  File "/virtualenv/src/aiopg/aiopg/pool.py", line 168, in _acquire
    with (yield from self._cond):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/locks.py", line 67, in __iter__
    yield from self.acquire()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/locks.py", line 176, in acquire
    yield from fut
concurrent.futures._base.CancelledError
```

Key point here is it was receiving `CancelledError` (client disconnect by timeout) while acquiring database connection from pool:

```
  File "/visio-longer/visio_longer/views/communicate/__init__.py", line 81, in legacy_communicate
    async with request.app["db"].acquire() as db:
```

I've had a coroutine running that was printing pool state (`size` and `freesize`) every 5 seconds and there was plenty of free connections in the pool at the moment!

Hours of investigation resulted in theory that receiving `CancelledError` while performing pool's context manager `__atexit__` was aborting the process of returning connection to the pool which resulted in pool malfunction. I've found a [commit](https://github.com/MagicStack/asyncpg/commit/537c8c9f4850899f0618d1a031641dfd3ed6986c) that was fixing that behaviour in `asyncpg`, `aioredis` contains similar code, I've also made an [awkward-looking fix](https://github.com/themylogin/aiopg/commit/cf2580671eabd880e8826d42ac04f5a3380447a7) to `aiopg`. None of this helped — I was still getting same errors from both `aioredis` and `aiopg`.

The situation resolved by replacing

```
async def handler(request):
    async with request.app["db"].acquire() as db:
        row = await query(db)

    return aiohttp.web.json_response(row)
```

by wrapping every piece of code that uses connection pools with `asyncio.shield`:

```
async def handler(request):
    async def process():
        async with request.app["db"].acquire() as db:
            row = await query(db)

    return aiohttp.web.json_response(asyncio.shield(process(row)))
```

So that aborted requests were still processed to their ends (including returning acquired resources to the pool).

Is it supposed to be this way? Now my code looks awful and there is no guarantee that next time I won't forgot wrapping my pools with `asyncio.shield`. What is the proper way of solving this problem (apparently libraries can't fix that themselves)?

Comment: I'm sure you will find https://vorpus.org/blog/control-c-handling-in-python-and-trio/ interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how this is any different than any other exception.  `CanceledError` is just another error.  All your context managers exit functions get run, so they should have an opportunity to release resources.
It semes like somehow a future related to a lock  in the connection pool is getting canceled.  That seems problematic and seems like it ought to be unrelated to the client connection being canceled.
I'm assuming there is a coroutine corresponding to the request in progress and that coroutine should be canceled when the connection is lost.
That call to `Task.cancel` will raise `CanceledError` inside the coroutine.  Assuming that `CanceledError` is eventually raised from the coroutine, the result of the `Task` will be `CanceledError`.
However I don't understand how the lock related future is becoming canceled.

If you are awaiting something in an exit function for a context manager, or the finally block, or some other cleanup code, you may need to take more care.  For example if you need a lock in an exit function to return some resource, then you may want a while loop that catches `CanceledError` (and eventually re-raises it) or to use async.shield.  I'd do that only around the specific code in the exit function/cleanup handler rather than around your entire request.
Also, consider whether using a callback to return your resource (via `loop.call_soon`) might be a better choice than awaiting in side cleanup code.
If cleanup code does not await, then a new `CanceledError` cannot be raised in it.  Context manager exit functions and finally blocks may be triggered by `CanceledError` elsewhere even if they do not await, but that is no different than any other exception

Comment: I was describing a situation where `CancelledError` was occuring inside context manager exit function. That would prevent it from finishing normally and leaving pool in consistent state.

Comment: How is that happening for tthe db connection exit func?  I'd kind of expect that returning a connection to the pool would not await anything. Updating the answer with some thoughts about exit functions though

Comment: All return-to-pool functions from libraries I've used await locking condition variable used to notify coroutines waiting for resource to be available in empty pool

Shielding this code did not help (maybe you can take a look at https://github.com/themylogin/aiopg/commit/cf2580671eabd880e8826d42ac04f5a3380447a7 and have a thought what's missing?)

Comment: That hardly seems like a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Stackoverflow is not for free debugging of large complex systems.:-)

Comment: Attempt to get an MCVE resulted in understanding that not only __aexit__, but __aenter__'s too should be guarded too. Thank you for your interest!